# Angular $http post to Express hangs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Anyone ever seen this?

If I do not include a data argument to my angular controller $http post, then the express side route is picked up and runs, but if I add a data element, it hangs and will not pick up the route - eventually Chrome debugger shows an error: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

This works:

```
              $scope.newAccount = function(){
                 console.log("Got a submit request for new account: " );
                 $http.post("http://localhost:3000/newAccount").success(function( data, status, headers, config ){
                 console.log("SUCCESS on NEW ACCOUNT");
                 $scope.mode = data;
              }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log("Got ERROR"); 
              });};
```

This does NOT work:

```
              $scope.newAccount = function(){
                 console.log("Got a submit request for new account: " );
                 $http.post("http://localhost:3000/newAccount",{info:"toSend"}).success(function( data, status, headers, config ){
                 console.log("SUCCESS on NEW ACCOUNT");
                 $scope.mode = data;
              }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log("Got ERROR");
              });
              };
```

This is the Express handler which does not change (actual logic stripped out):

```
    app.post('/newAccount', function (req, res) {

        console.log("GOT A POST REQUEST: " );
             ....some code here
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.send( "successful post" );
    });
```

Comment: Are you using bodyParser?

Comment: Yes, using :var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: First thing to do is ensure that you don't have any other middleware that could affect it. Perhaps put some sort of blank middleware (maybe after bodyparser) that just console.log's the request and calls next() afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that this issue was related to remote access authorization.  Chrome debugger gave some pretty lame info.  Firefox debugger was much clearer.    Previously I had set the res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); in the route handler directly just before sending a response.  That fixed this same issue for the original call without a data element.  However, in order to get this to work with a data element, the following had to be added to my Express application - rather than setting in the route handler itself.  A better programming practice for sure, but I was just hacking some things out to learn about Node / Express.  Wasted a lot of time on this one.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
    });
```